# How open a .log file in Notepad with Python without the file continuing to be linked to Python execution?

Tags: windows, python

When I open the Windows file explorer and double-click the `test_errors.log` file, it opens in Notepad and I can edit it by directly saving the edits with `Control + S`.

But I want to do this with Python, but as the code opens the file and wait for me to reply the `input` to continue execution, when I try to save the edits using `Control + S` it opens the window to save as a new file:

[image]

```python
from pathlib import Path
import logging
import sys
import os

CODE_NAME_FILE = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
ERROR_LOG_FILE = f'{CODE_NAME_FILE}_errors.log'

def setup_logger(logger_name: str, log_file: str, level: int = logging.DEBUG) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger

def log_exception(comments: str | int | float = '') -> None:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    if tb is not None:
        logger.error(f"Line Error: {tb.tb_lineno}\nComments: {comments}", exc_info=True)
    else:
        logger.error(f"log_exception() called without an active exception.\nComments: {comments}")

logger = setup_logger(__name__, ERROR_LOG_FILE)

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            # works
        except Exception as e:
            log_exception()
            os.startfile(Path(ERROR_LOG_FILE).resolve())
            input("Log is open to analyze the error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the code were like this, just opening the file and finishing execution, I can save it as I want because the Python code doesn't continue running:

```python
from pathlib import Path
import os

ERROR_LOG_FILE = "test_errors.log"
os.startfile(Path(ERROR_LOG_FILE).resolve())
```

PS: using automated movements with the mouse (pyautogui) or keyboard (pynput.keyboard) to find the file and open it as done manually cannot be an option because I use the computer for other things while the file is not opened.

How can I open it with Python without the file being linked to the execution of the Python file?